# How to add extension function to nock.Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock

I am using nock in an angular/typescript server-side application's unit tests. I have a complex set of requests that get made often, and I would like to re-use the same set of nock requests for multiple unit tests. I would like to add functions to nock.Scope that would allow me to setup my unit tests like this:

```
const req = nock('http://some-base-server.com/')
  .mockPermissions(param1, param2)
  .get('/unique-request-for-unit-test')
  .reply(200, {data: true});
```

I've tried creating a testHelper.ts file like so:

```
import nock from 'nock';

module 'nock' {
  class Scope {
    mockPermissions(param1: string, param2: string): Scope;
  }
}

nock.Scope.prototype.mockPermissions = function(param1: string, param2: string) {
  return this
    .get('/permission')
    .reply(200, { permission: data })
    .get('/group')
    .reply(200, { group: data });
};
```

Although my example attempts compiles fine, during runtime it basically says that nock.Scope cannot be found.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for you because `Scope` is only exported as a type from the library, the class as a value is not made public.
You can see what values are exported [here in the index file](https://github.com/nock/nock/blob/master/index.js).

I'd also, personally, recommend against this approach in general. Modifying the prototype of an object you don't fully control tends to be considered a code-smell since it can lead to unexpected issues down the road.

When I've been in your shoes before, I've gone the route of creating helper functions that pre-build nocks. I usually put them with the same test helpers that create other factories.

For your code, as an example, I would create something like:

```
export function nockAuthForBaseService(param1: string, param2: string) {
  return nock('http://some-base-server.com/')
    .get('/permission')
    .reply(200, { permission: param1 })
    .get('/group')
    .reply(200, { group: param2 });
}
```

Then I can call and reuse this factory from various tests to DRY them up.

Wether you pass in an existing nock instance or not if fully up to you. I've never had the scenario where the interceptors I wanted nocked were reused across services so it made it nicer for my code to have the helper know the base URL. Just one less piece of overhead for tests to not need.